# Many errors on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've just started using C++ like an hour  ago and I also just started coding 2 weeks ago, my first project is Visual Novel which I make with engine called Ren'py (A python based engine). I wanna learn how to program with Visual Studio, if anyone can help me I'd be grateful.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Nama saya adalah " << a;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the errors
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'a' ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\admin\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp 8
Error   C2065   'string': undeclared identifier ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\admin\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp 8
Error   C2065   'cout': undeclared identifier   ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\admin\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp 10
Error   C2065   'cin': undeclared identifier    ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\admin\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp 9
Error   C2065   'a': undeclared identifier  ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\admin\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp 8
Error   C2065   'a': undeclared identifier  ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\admin\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp 9
Error   C2065   'a': undeclared identifier  ConsoleApplication2 c:\users\admin\source\repos\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp 10

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` this *has* to be the first line in your file.

Comment: I am very impressed that you are starting with C++ but it could be very frustrating and discourage you. What about trying vb.net or C# as a first language. You can get up and running much faster and some of the concepts will prepare you for C++.

Comment: @Mary Thanks for the advice, I would reconsider it.

Answer (score 1):

`#include "stdafx.h"` should be the first line of the file. Any lines before it are ignored, so you get errors because `string` is not recognized.

Comment: Ah it worked! I didn't know that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It boggles my mind that Visual Studio doesn't flag this as an error.

Comment: Yeah, Visual Studio should flag this as an error bcs there will be a lot like me that doesn't know about it.

Comment: I highly recommend not using Precompiled Headers.  You've encountered one of many reasons.  Also, for small programs, there is no negligible savings in build time.  Remember, if any header in the precompiled headers changes, the precompiled header has to be recompiled as well as all sources that use the precompiled header.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews once you add in windows.h it starts becoming noticeable

Comment: @MarkRansom It boggles mine that precompiled headers are on by default...

Comment: It's a holdover setting, it used to make a huge difference for even small programs. That was 20+ years ago but MS is extremely conservative about changing such things.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the intent of stdafx.h is that it would only contain headers that don't change, like the C++ standard, Windows, and MFC headers. Unfortunately it requires some discipline to make that happen, too many times people will dump headers in there just for convenience so they don't have to include them in all the sources that require them.